# Isometry (Riemannian geometry) on a simple example

Tags: differential-topology, isometry

I'm trying to understand the concept of isometry ([Isometry (Riemannian geometry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry_(Riemannian_geometry))) on a specific problem. I think I have to interpret $f^*$ as $$g(v,w) = f^* g'(v,w) = (df_{v,w})^* g'(f(v),f(w)),$$ where $(df_{v,w})^*$ is the transpose matrix of $df_{v,w}$. Could anyone be able to explain to me that concept on a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example is translation in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Perhaps a slightly
more interesting case is polar coordinates. Take $M=M'=\mathbb{R}^{2}$,
$f=$ identity. On $\left(M,g\right)$, take polar coordinates, and
on $\left(M',g'\right)$ the Euclidean chart.

Fix a point $p\in M\backslash\left\{ 0\right\} $, $p=\left(r,\theta\right)=\left(x,y\right)$,
with $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$. Then $g'=dx^{2}+dy^{2}$,
and 
\begin{align*}
f_{*}\left(\partial_{r}\right) & =\cos\theta\partial_{x}+\sin\theta\partial_{y}\\
f_{*}\left(\partial_{\theta}\right) & =-r\sin\theta\partial_{x}+r\cos\theta\partial_{y}\\
g\left(\partial_{r},\partial_{r}\right) & =g'\left(f_{*}\left(\partial_{r}\right),f_{*}\left(\partial_{r}\right)\right)=1\\
g\left(\partial_{r},\partial_{\theta}\right) & =g'\left(f_{*}\left(\partial_{r}\right),f_{*}\left(\partial_{\theta}\right)\right)=0\\
g\left(\partial_{\theta},\partial_{\theta}\right) & =g'\left(f_{*}\left(\partial_{\theta}\right),f_{*}\left(\partial_{\theta}\right)\right)=r^{2}.
\end{align*}
That is, $g=dr^{2}+r^{2}d\theta^{2}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just a little detail could help me; could you just take time to explain roughly the notation $g = dr^2 + r^2 d \theta ^2$?

Comment: Yes, the metric tensor is $g=g_{\alpha\beta}dx^{\alpha}\otimes dx^{\beta}$,
but `$\otimes$' is usually dropped, so it becomes $g=g_{\alpha\beta}dx^{\alpha}dx^{\beta}$. 

In polar coordinates, the coefficients are $g_{rr}=g\left(\partial_{r},\partial_{r}\right)=1$,
$g_{r\theta}=g_{\theta r}=g\left(\partial_{r},\partial_{\theta}\right)=0$,
and $g_{\theta\theta}=g\left(\partial_{\theta},\partial_{\theta}\right)=r^{2}$.
Also, $dr\otimes dr=dr^{2}$, $d\theta\otimes d\theta=d\theta^{2}$,
etc.